# Tail recursion in clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure, tail-recursion

This is a lisp code that uses tail recursion.

```
(defun factorial (f n)
    (if (= n 1)
        f
        (factorial (* f n) (- n 1))))
```

I translate this into clojure code expecting the same tail recursion optimization.

```
(defn fact [f n]
    (if (= n 1)
        f
        (fact (* f n) (dec n))))
```

However I got this integer overflow (not stack overflow) even with small number such as `(fact 1 30)`.

```
ArithmeticException integer overflow  clojure.lang.Numbers.throwIntOverflow (Numbers.java:1374)
```

I tried with `recur`, but got the same error.

```
(defn factorial [f n]
    (if (= n 1)
        f
        (recur (* f n) (dec n))))
```

What's wrong with the clojure code?

Comment: Also it's worth noting that Clojure, because of limitations of the JVM, doesn't support automatic tail call optimization.  `recur` is indeed the way to go for a recursive idiom in this case.

Comment: Where in the clojure docs can I find examples of using recur without loop? The way you have used it here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nothing, just use `BigInt`s:

```
(factorial 1N 30N) ;=> 265252859812191058636308480000000N
```

The arguments may be small, but the result is not!

Note that ticked versions of the arithmetic operators are also available, which support arbitrary precision:

```
(reduce *' (range 1 31)) ;=> 265252859812191058636308480000000N
```